# Where do I add a new table's name in wpdb?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I've manually setup a new table in the `wp-db` database. Where do I add the name of this table in the `wpdb` class or anywhere else?

I've noticed that WordPress uses queries like:
`$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users" );` where the actual table name isn't used.

If I were to do:
`$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->friends" );` it will not work.

I also tried adding the name like `var $friends;` inside the `wpdb` class, but that would not work.

Comment: Please show us _how_ you added the table `$friends` to `$wpdb`. Probably that's your problem.

Comment: I added it manually to the db, since I only need to select some stuff from it and display. That's why I asked where I could simply add it's name, so I could use it like `$wpdb->myTable`. I'm just beginning with this thing.

Answer (score 3):

`$wpdb->tables[] = 'friends';` is the basic code you're looking for.

Please note that you'll want to test for the existence of the table in the list so you don't wind up with 100 copies of the table in the tables array, especially if there's a chance your code could be repeated within a page load.

UPDATED with example:

```
add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'add_table' );

function add_table() {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! in_array( 'friends', $wpdb->tables ) ) {
         $wpdb->tables[] = 'friends';
    }
}
```

Comment: Please wrap that in the proper hook.

Comment: Good call, @kaiser - updated.

Comment: If your table is global on multisite, you can use `$wpdb->global_tables` instead. (Please note that both of these are marked with `@access private` though.)

Answer (score 1):

Do not modify your `wpdb` class at all! It's a bad habit. Next time when WordPress update it's version you will loose all your changes.

Instead of modifying `wpdb` class, create a table name variable (or constant) withing your plugin and use it when you need it.

For instance, in your `myplugin.php` file add following:

```
global $wpdb;
define( 'MYPLUGIN_TABLE_FRIENDS', $wpdb->prefix . 'friends' );
```

And then in your queries use it like this:

```
$user_count = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " . MYPLUGIN_TABLE_FRIENDS );
```

**UPDATED:**

> Ok. Fine. But just for my knowledge, since I'm new to all this, how
>   does WordPress do it, and where are they stored?

Those tables are set when `$wpdb->set_prefix()` method is called. Take a look at [this method](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L660) and you focus on [673-685 lines](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/wp-db.php#L673).

Comment: Ok. Fine. But just for my knowledge, since I'm new to all this, how does WordPress do it, and where are they stored?

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: +1 but IMO no need to define (another) constant. Should be enough to simply use `"{$wpdb->prefix}friends"`... _imo_

Comment: @kaiser it's just and example, like i said: `create a table name variable (or constant)`

Comment: One reason not to use a constant is that your code will not switch over to another blog when using `switch_to_blog()` on multisite. Your table name will still be defined with the old prefix.

Answer (score 1):

**Eugene Manuilov** answer is a good solution. However if you want use the `$wpdb->table_name` syntax you can

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'add_table_name');

function add_table_name() {
  global $wpdb;
  $wpdb->friends = $wpdb->prefix . 'friends';
}
```

Comment: @murdaugh's answer is better, because the prefix for the table will get updated properly when using `switch_to_blog()` on multisite. Whereas if you use this method, you will still be using the old table prefix, meaning that your code won't actually switch to the other blog. It is stuck on the original blog.

Comment: @J.D. to be multisite compatible just add `add_action( 'switch_blog', 'add_table_name' );`